# Ts compilation command - kill tsc from terminal

Tags: node.js, tsc

I cant find any solution on how to kill the tsc command

those are my scripts in package json

```
{
"dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/server.ts",
"build": "tsc && --exit && echo 'TypeScript compilation completed.'",
"server": "pm2 start dist/server.js --name Superim-BE && pm2 save",
}
```

i need to kill the build process because i created CI/CD with yaml that after deploying the repo it will run build and then will run npm run server but it couldnt due to it still on the build command that never end.

-> will glad to hear how to kill the tsc command
-> open to new approach (i dont want run tsc command before deploying )